# Slack workspace app: Rotating and refreshing token

Tags: token, slack, slack-api, refresh-token

I am trying to enable token rotation in my slack workspace app. But I cannot seem to match Slack API documentation with my slack app's settings > OAuth & Permissions page

#### I cannot find the option to enable token expiration and Refresh Token.

#### This is what the documentation says:

[image: This is what the documentation says:]

#### This is what I find in my app's Settings > OAuth & Permissions panel

[image: This is what I find in my app's Settings > OAuth & Permissions panel]

Please if have anyone faced this and solved, help me out. I am not sure about this problem, but I cannot seem to find any solution online.

Comment: workspace apps and workspace tokens are officially deprecated. I would strongly suggest to make a normal Slack app instead. See here for reference: https://api.slack.com/legacy-workspace-apps

Comment: Did you think about using a dedicated tool to do that? Something like [Bearer](https://www.bearer.sh) should help a lot on that (full disclaimer: I'm working there)